# Android get Manifest merger failed Error on using tools:replace

Tags: android

in my project as far as i'm using more library i have to use `tools:replace` for overriding some features such as `supportsRtl`, when i add tools name space and use `tools:replace="android:supportsRtl,android:allowBackup"` on application tag i get this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

manifest content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="com.myapp.androidapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:name=".APP"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:supportsRtl,android:allowBackup">

        <activity android:name=".Ui.ActivityStartUpApplication">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Ui.ApplicationRobot.view.ActivityRegisterRobot"
            android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".Ui.ActivityChannelContent.view.ActivityChannelContent"
            android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation">

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Ui.ActivityMain.view.ActivityMain"
            android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

problem resolved by adding

```
android:supportsRtl="false"
```

before

```
tools:replace="android:supportsRtl,android:allowBackup"
```